# Can't relate a part of the code to a button

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I made a small and simple program (I'm a newbie), and they a proceded to do the code. The thing is, I don't know why, one part of the code isn't directed to a button as it is supposed to. They have the same name.
How do I direct it.
The code says:

```
Private Sub Boton1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    If lblcalculadora.Text = "0" Then
        lblcalculadora.Text = "1"
    Else
        lblcalculadora.Text = lblcalculadora.Text + "1"
    End If
```

And Design page the button is called "Boton1_clicl". But when I doubleclick that button, it creates a new private sub called Boton1_click_1.
How can I connect the first part of the code with that button. I know it's a realy stupid matter, but I'm really stuck in here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing `Handles Boton1.Click`

```
Private Sub Boton1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Boton1.Click
    If lblcalculadora.Text = "0" Then
        lblcalculadora.Text = "1"
    Else
        lblcalculadora.Text = lblcalculadora.Text + "1"
    End If
```

Comment: Thank you GJKH and @LarsTech

Comment: No problem, be sure to upvote any answers you found helpful and select one as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the handler:

```
Private Sub Boton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Boton1.Click
```